# jquery mobile slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I hava a jquery mobile slider.

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" data-theme="d" data-highlight="true"/>
```

My question is that is there a way to change the color of the highlight fill on the track of the slider? (By default its blue ).

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can define specific themes for your jqm components: [http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/themes.html](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/themes.html) or you could try playing with css... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Littm: I didn't want to change the whole theme of the slider, I only wanted to change the color of the highlight fill.

I found the answer though:

We just need to override one class which jqm applies.

```
div.ui-btn-active{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#FF0000),to(#6FACD5)) !important;
}
```

Its working ..!!